# Student of Industrial Engineering or Student at Industrial Engineering?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

What is the correct choice of preposition here:

> Student **of** Industrial Engineering

or

> Student **at** Industrial Engineering

or anything else?

Comment: "Of", but you'll have to add more detail so we can understand why this is confusing for you.

Comment: I mean as an occupation

Comment: Yes, we know.  Can you add more detail which you think might be correct, and which is incorrect, and why?  Perhaps it's related to something you read in an English textbook, or on a website?

Comment: as Linkedin headline what can I use?

Comment: @MAHBUBRAFI What Andrew means is that you should provide more linguistical context for the confusion or uncertainty you are experiencing. For example, *I'm not sure that "of" is correct, because doesn't "of" show possession?* This site works best when questions focus on some aspect of English that is unclear rather than on some specific text where the correct word is not known.

Comment: As an occupation? "Industrial Engineering" could be a company, where you are an intern. *"I am a student at Industrial Engineering."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you study industrial engineering, you are a student **of** industrial engineering.

If you study at an institution, university, school or company named **Industrial Engineering**, you are a student at **Industrial Engineering**.

Answer (score 0):

"Student of Industrial Engineering" is OK. "Student *at* ... " does not sound good, at least in US style English.
Best in my opinion would be, "Industrial Engineering student."

Comment: There isn't enough context in the question, as commented.